# Sending a signal from RaspberryPi to Android by Button in Java

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I'm making a smart interphone.
If button(raspberryPi) is pressed, smartphone(app) rings.
So I need to Socket Communication.
Because I don't know socket... , I copied it.
I should use Java (android), I found Java pi4v library.

I have server(RaspberryPi) code, client(Android) code, and button code.
But, they're respective and I don't know how to combine them.
I want to send any signal pi to android using button!

Here is Server code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class JavaSocketServer{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                try{
                int portNumber = 10001;
                System.out.println("Start Server...");
                ServerSocket aServerSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
                System.out.println("Listening at port " + portNumber + ",,,");

                while(true){
                Socket sock = aServerSocket.accept();
                InetAddress clientHost = sock.getLocalAddress();
                int clientPort = sock.getPort();
                System.out.println("A client connected.");
                System.out.println("(host : " + clientHost + ", port : " + clientPort);

                ObjectInputStream instream = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                Object obj = instream.readObject();
                System.out.println("Input : " + obj);

                ObjectOutputStream outstream = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                outstream.writeObject(obj + " from Server.");
                outstream.flush();
                sock.close();
                }
                } catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Here is Android Client Code.

```
package org.techtown.socket;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * 
 *
 * @author Mike
 *
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText input01;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        input01 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input01);

        // 버튼 이벤트 처리
        Button button01 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button01);
        button01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String addr = input01.getText().toString().trim();

                ConnectThread thread = new ConnectThread(addr);
                thread.start();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * 소켓 연결할 스레드 정의
     */
    class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        String hostname;

        public ConnectThread(String addr) {
            hostname = addr;
        }

        public void run() {

            try {
                int port = 11001;

                Socket sock = new Socket(hostname, port);
                ObjectOutputStream outstream = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
                outstream.writeObject("Hello AndroidTown on Android");
                outstream.flush();

                ObjectInputStream instream = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
                String obj = (String) instream.readObject();

                Log.d("MainActivity", "서버에서 받은 메시지 : " + obj);

                sock.close();

            } catch(Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Here is Button code.

```
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.*;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent;
import com.pi4j.io.gpio.event.GpioPinListenerDigital;

/**
* This example code demonstrates how to setup a listener
* for GPIO pin state changes on the Raspberry Pi.
*
* @author Robert Savage
*/
public class ListenGpioExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("<--Pi4J--> GPIO Listen Example ... started.");

        // create gpio controller
        final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();

        // provision gpio pin #02 as an input pin with its internal pull down resistor enabled
        final GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_04, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);

        // set shutdown state for this input pin
        myButton.setShutdownOptions(true);

        // create and register gpio pin listener
        myButton.addListener(new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
            @Override
            public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
                // display pin state on console
                System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
            }

        });

        System.out.println(" ... complete the GPIO #02 circuit and see the listener feedback here in the console.");

        // keep program running until user aborts (CTRL-C)
while(true) {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }

            // stop all GPIO activity/threads by shutting down the GPIO controller
            // (this method will forcefully shutdown all GPIO monitoring threads and scheduled tasks)
            // gpio.shutdown();   <--- implement this method call if you wish to terminate the Pi4J GPIO
     controller
        }
    }
```

I have no Idea,,,,

Comment: You should use outstream.write(message) to send something to the client. But you already directly closed the client socket so you cant anymore.

Comment: Where is the Android specific code?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Sorry, it is now updated

Comment: Your port numbers for the server and client are different(10001 and 11001).

Comment: Ah, it is corrected